# Acumatica - Moving Credit Hold from Sales Orders to Shipments

Tags: acumatica

We are a manufacturer and credit hold does not stop production rather the release of a shipment.
To overcome this I would like to recreate the event handlers, OnCreditLimitSatisfied & OnCreditLimitViolated, within the Shipment graph.

Does anyone have any advice or insight into how these event handlers are written?

Thanks,

Aleks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something you might achieve by creating/customising States and Workflows for the Sales Order and/or Shipment forms.

You can customise these workflows to update the status and available actions of a document based on a range of conditions/actions etc.

More info:
https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/reporting/w150-workflows/

Comment: Thanks Graeme, I have tried this avenue but with the credit hold does not trigger on Shipments if you base the event handler off of the SOOrder+Events CreditLimitViolated/Satisfied. Perhaps I should have phrased my question a bit better, I would like to write the event handlers in the same way they are written in the SOOrder+Events graph.